# Jar dependency management in Kettle

Tags: dependencies, executable-jar, kettle

Is there a way to specify dependent jars in Kettle while calling a jar file? or do i have to include all dependent jars with jar being called by kettle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

according to the wiki:http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kettle+dependency+management,kettle uses Apache Ivy to manager jars dependence.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, they all need to be included. So obviously you also have to be aware of pre-existing ones too.  But to be sure I would check on the kettle-dev mailing list - get very good quick answers on there.